# decoding ctypes structures

Tags: python, structure, ctypes

I'm trying to get my head around ctypes in python, and I'm able to get some simple things working, but when it comes to unpacking c structs I find myself running into some difficulties. I decided that to learn this I should play around a bit, and while I know the socket standard library implements `gethostbyname_ex()`, I thought I'd make an attempt at implementing it using `ctypes` and `libc.gethostbyname()`.

I'm able to execute `libc.gethostbyname()` fairly easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ctypes import *

cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
he = libc.gethostbyname("www.google.com")
```

But that gives me a `hostent` data-structure. I thought the best way to unpack this would be to grab the c struct and create a class which inherits from `ctypes.Structure`, and so I came up with this (I found the `hostent` struct definition in `netdb.h`):

```
class hostent(Structure):
    '''
    struct hostent
    {
      char *h_name;                 /* Official name of host.  */
      char **h_aliases;             /* Alias list.  */
      int h_addrtype;               /* Host address type.  */
      int h_length;                 /* Length of address.  */
      char **h_addr_list;           /* List of addresses from name server. */
    }
    '''
    _fields_ = [("h_name", c_char_p), ("h_aliases", POINTER(c_char_p)),
                ("h_addrtype", c_int), ("h_length", c_int),
                ("h_addr_list", POINTER(c_char_p))]
```

Where I'm unclear is whether I've setup the `h_aliases` and the `h_addr_list` fields correctly, because whenever I attempt to access them as arrays, even at the 0th index after a lookup of something that I know has at least one alias and at least one address, I get a NULL pointer access `ValueError` exception:

```
>>> he = hostent(libc.gethostbyname("www.google.com"))
>>> pprint.pprint(he.h_addr_list)
<__main__.LP_c_char_p object at 0xb75dae84>
>>> print he.h_addr_list[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/py2659JxK", line 24, in <module>
    print he.h_addr_list[0]
ValueError: NULL pointer access
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define what the return type of `gethostbyname` is:

```
>>> libc.gethostbyname.restype = POINTER(hostent)
>>> he = libc.gethostbyname("www.google.com")[0]
>>> he.h_aliases[0]
'www.google.com'
```

Also, `h_addr_list` should not be declared as `POINTER(c_char_p)`, because `c_char_p` is used for null-terminated strings. In this case `POINTER(POINTER(c_ubyte))` would be better, and then the first address would be `he.h_addr_list[0][:4]` if it's an IPv4 address.

Comment: Thank you. How can I know how long the `h_addr_list` and `h_aliases` arrays are? Calling `len()` on them doesn't work, and if I go beyond the end of the arrays I get a segfault, not a catchable exception.

Comment: @Dyslexic: I think the last entry will be null, and you can check for a null pointer by converting to bool, e.g.: `if not he.h_addr_list[idx]: print 'null'`

Comment: One more thing, with the prototype as it is in netdb.h, how do you know to setup `char **h_aliases` as `POINTER(c_char_p)` and `char **h_addr_list` as `POINTER(POINTER(c_ubyte))`. Is it just a matter of experience and knowledge of the way the c struct is used?

Comment: @Dyslexic you can't tell from the header file alone. Ideally the documentation would say which strings are null-terminated. It doesn't in this case but there really can be no other way: `h_aliases` strings must be null-terminated because there's no other way to determine their length. And `h_addr_list` entries can't be null-terminated, because they may contain zeroes, so you have the `h_length` field to specify the length. In general, readable strings will usually be null-terminated in C APIs, while binary data will not.

Comment: I've got some more questions about error checking, but I'll start a new question for them so that if you answer it, you can get some kind of credit. Thanks for all your help. FYI The code I generated is stashed in https://github.com/mkomitee/ctypes.